# How to detect if there is any file added in a folder in Windows?

Tags: powershell, windows

Is it a way to detect if there is any file added in a folder? Include the sub-folder.

For example, check if any text file *.txt is added in folder c:\data-files\ or its sub-folders.

The folder can be shared folder of another machine too.

Comment: This is rather vague. Do you want to look for new files in a folder?

Comment: I need to run a script if any new file is added to the folder.

Comment: Find a buddy who knows C# or Powershell. 10 minutes of work with the System.IO.FileSystemWatcher class.  http://blog.iisreset.me/2014/04/bigbrothershell-detect-and-suppress-those-files.html

Comment: @RyanRies `FileSystemWatcher` seems not work with shared folder. e.g. `\\xxxx\sss\sss`.

Comment: @NickW Yep, it does. As long as the share is not Samba or some other non-Windows goo. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151804/system-io-filesystemwatcher-to-monitor-a-network-server-folder-performance-con

Comment: @RyanRies I tried it on an shared folder of Windows server 2003. It didn't trigger the script. However, local folder works. How to check if the sharing is Samba?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The System.IO.FileSystemWatcher monitors the file system for changes, such as a file being created or deleted.  It can monitor directories recursively, and it can monitor file shares across a network. Since it is a .NET class, it can be used by C#, Visual Basic, and even Powershell. What you do with the notification events is up to you.

Here is an example from Mathias R. Jessen: http://blog.iisreset.me/2014/04/bigbrothershell-detect-and-suppress-those-files.html

And here is a good StackOverflow post about using the FileSystemWatcher to monitor a remote file share:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151804/system-io-filesystemwatcher-to-monitor-a-network-server-folder-performance-con